# How check if string specifies directory?

Tags: c++

Suppose there is a some string:

```
std::string some_string = "some_string";
```

And I want to know if `chdir(some_string.c_str())` will return -1 or not without calling it. Is there quick way to do this?

P.S. I want my code to work also for windows, there I'm going to use `_chdir()`

Comment: Actually on msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1(v=vs.80).aspx) there is an example where _chdir is used to check if the directory exists, so apparently there is no simple way to do that without calling the function. Why don't you want to call it?

Comment: you always need to check file/dir stuff after calling anyway. you cant prevent some other process deleting the directory after you check and before running chdir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#ifdef WIN32
# include <io.h>
#else
# include <unistd.h>
#endif

int access(const char *pathname, int mode);
// check user's permissions for a file
```

int mode values:

00 - Existence only,
02 - Write-only,
04 - Read-only,
06 - Read and write.

Function returns 0 if the file has the given mode.

Comment: I've heard of issues with access on Windows when ACL is in use. I don't have documentation but it's something to look out for.

Comment: @Andrew White: I haven't heard it, but anything could be happened.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but I thought the OP wanted to know how to check if the path is a *directory*, not whether it's in the filesystem (as either a file or directory), which is what access() does.  I think you can use stat for this, via the macro S_ISDIR (See this: http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Boost's is_directory function](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#is_directory), you can find more info on [Boost's Filesystem Reference page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know if `chdir(some_string.c_str())` will return -1 or not without calling it

You need to be careful about making those kinds of checks. The problem is if you rely on their result, because, in between you making the check and performing an operation that relies on the check, another process might have performed an operation (`rmdir` in this case) that invalidates the assumptin in your code. That is, you can introduce a race hazard into your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want it to work for Windows, use [`GetFileAttributes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which returns [`File Attribute Constants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[`GetFileAttributesEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is even better.

Comment: I want it to work not only for windows, but also for windows :)